# Calling service depend on PathVariable using single controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, controller

I need to call implementation service from single controller depend on PathVariable

```
/{variable}/doSomething

public void controller(@PathVariable("variable") variable)

if variable == 1

  call service1Impl();

else if variable == 2

  call service2Impl();
```

but I need my controller plain like this and not using if, else

```
public void controller(...) {
  call service();
}
```

I need to find some solution for auto-configuration my app when getting any PathVariable, it should know which service needs to call.

I try to using

- load Config.class as context - @Configuration

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class AppConfig {

  @Bean(name = "variableValue1")
  public DummyService getService1() {
      return new DummyServiceImpl();
  }

  @Bean(name = "variableValue2")
  public AnotherService getService2() {
      return new AnotherServiceImpl();
  }
  ```

  but in controller I need to load this config as context then its not plain enough
- bean factory

its work but my controller not enough plain for me

I need to do like this one but it must based on PathVariable not property name.

```
@Configuration
public class GreetingServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "language.name", havingValue = "english", matchIfMissing = true)
    public GreetingService englishGreetingService() {
        return new EnglishGreetingService();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "language.name", havingValue = "french")
    public GreetingService frenchGreetingService() {
        return new FrenchGreetingService();
    }
}
------------------------------------------------
    @RestController
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    GreetingService greetingService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return greetingService.greet();
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask why? There's a number of ways I can think of that could pull this off but all are quite unsavoury.

Comment: @Captain I don't know why, I get it from requirement XD

Comment: Question - can you have two separate controller methods for each type of greeting?

Comment: @EamonScullion Yes, I can

Answer (score 1):

So based on the pathvariable, the specific method needs to be executed..

This is just a suggestion, since you dont want to go for if else

you can use Hashmap for this,

```
 HashMap<Integer, Runnable> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Runnable> ();
```

For example,

pathvariable is 1 -> method be executed is method1()

pathvariable is 2 -> method be executed is method2()

```
hm.put(1, method1())
hm.put(2, method2())
```

So in controller,

if PathVariable is 1,

```
hm.get(1).run(); // hm.get(variable).run()
```

Comment: Thank for answer but still look like using if, else